# Why new password is saved even if you don't respect validation strength meter?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I am trying to increase the security of my website and user account settings. So I wanted to insert a password strength meter to give the password a security level. Everything works correctly but it seems to be just a question of style.

When you change your password, even if you do not respect the rules imposed in the strength meter you are still allowed to wash the password and the settings are successful.

So how can I prevent this? I wish the settings would not be saved if you don't respect the strength meter, otherwise it makes no sense.

I'm working with wordpress, but the form account setting belongs to woocommerce. Can some Good Samaritan help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help, thanks.

```js
/* Show Hide Password */    
function showPassword(targetID) {
    var pw = document.getElementById(targetID);
    if (pw.type === "password") {
      pw.type = "text";
    } else {
      pw.type = "password";
    }
  }

/*Add class Active to Modifica password*/
document.getElementById('editpw').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('actived');
}
  
/* Dropdown Password Field */
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_btn');
iconDrop = null;
lastOpened = null; //Add this for toggling dropdown
  
 dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dropCont = this.nextElementSibling;
    let icon = this.querySelector('.icon_item');
    icon.classList.toggle("down");
    dropCont.classList.toggle("show");
  
    //Add this for toggling dropdown
    if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== dropCont)
    lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
    lastOpened = dropCont;
  
    if (iconDrop && iconDrop !== icon)
    iconDrop.classList.remove("down");
    iconDrop = icon;
  }));

/*Start Password Strength Meter*/
var myInput = document.getElementById("password_1");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
  
// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

```css
/*Form Style*/
.form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%) 0px 5px 15px -5px;
  border: 1px solid var(--e-global-color-2075d85);
}
.box-name-surname { 
  display: flex; gap: 20px; 
}
.form-row { 
  width: 100%; margin-bottom: 18px!important; 
}

.edit-account-button { height: 30px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; }


fieldset { 
  border: 0!important; margin: 0!important; padding: 5px!important; 
}

/*Input fields*/
input.field-settings {
    width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px!important;
  border: 2px solid #efefef!important;
  padding: 12px!important;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 15px;
}

input.field-settings:focus {
  border: 2px solid #6FA4F2!important;
}

input.field-settings.disabled {
    background: var(--e-global-color-2606bfd);
    color: var(--e-global-color-43596cc);
}

label.t2 {
    font-size: 14px!important;
    line-height: 1.5em!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
    margin-bottom: 6px!important;
    display: block;
}

span.t4-light {
    margin: 0 6px;
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
}

/*Toggle Password*/
.togglePw { display: none; margin-bottom: 0;}

.togglePw + label:before { 
    content: "\f06e"; 
    font: var(--fa-font-solid); 
    margin-bottom: 6px; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
    display: block;
    color: #8C9099;
}

.togglePw:checked + label:before { 
    content: "\f070"; 
    font: var(--fa-font-solid);
    margin-bottom: 6px; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
    display: block;
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.input-group { display: flex; align-items: center; }

/*Dropdown Function Style*/
.drop_btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.drop_btn:hover {
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.drop_btn.actived {
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.icon_item {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f078';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.icon_item.down {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f325';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 900px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/*Pasword Strength Meter*/
/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}
```

```html
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="form-container" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

   <div class="box-name-surname">
        <p class="form-row">
             <label class="t2" for="account_first_name">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
           <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="John" />
      </p>
      <p class="form-row">
           <label class="t2" for="account_last_name">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
           <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="Doe" />
      </p>
   </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row">
        <label class="t2" for="account_user_login">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="field-settings disabled" name="account_user_login" id="account_user_login" disabled value="JohnDoeUser" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <label class="t2" for="account_display_name">Display Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="John Doe" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row email">
        <label class="t2" for="account_email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="field-settings" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="JohnDoe@example.com" />
    </p>

    <!-- Password Section -->
    <div id="editpw" class="drop_btn">Edit Password<i class="icon_item fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
    <div class="drop_container">
        <fieldset>  
         <p class="">
               <label class="t2" for="password_current">Current Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off"/>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_current" onclick="showPassword('password_current')"/>
                  <label for="pw_current" class="fa"></label>
               </div>
         </p>

           <p class="">
               <label class="t2" for="password_1">New Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
                  <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_1" onclick="showPassword('password_1')"/>
                  <label for="pw_1" class="fa"></label>
            </div>
         </p>

           <p class="">
            <label class="t2" for="password_2">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
                   <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_2" onclick="showPassword('password_2')"/>
                   <label for="pw_2" class="fa"></label>
        </div>
       </p>
       
    </fieldset>

          <div id="message">
            <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
            <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
            <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
            <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
            <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">Save Changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for your comment. I'm not a dev, but fan that looking to learn. I need if else to close and open the password tab. Why do you think it doesn't make sense? Excuse the question, I try to learn from those who know more than me.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Why does it make no sense. Seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @epascarello it makes sense, sorry. I was looking at the not well indented code and thought if was all in the same function scope - related to the rest of the logic. My bad. Now I realized it was a standalone feature for toggling Stars/text password. :\

Comment: Right now your validation is only visual. You don't have anything to stop the form submission if the password is not strong enough. You will also want something server-side to check the password strength in case the javascript is disabled or bypassed.

Comment: Where is the validation on submit? I see no actual submission checks.

Comment: Since I'm working with wordpress / woocommerce the submit controls are in another file: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-form-handler.html Start line 218

Comment: @epascarello Here is woocommerce's original password-strength-meter script. I hadn't noticed it, I think with this I can be able to apply to my custom form. But I'm not sure how to do it, I'm new to all of this. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5175a6820b1ea78160ba6dfeafa67e9a3e0a6c59/plugins/woocommerce/client/legacy/js/frontend/password-strength-meter.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of looking for a solution I found one. I realized woocommerce provides its own password strength meter, but I didn't know it was there. Since it's already there I've used that.

**Password Strength Meter file**: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5175a6820b1ea78160ba6dfeafa67e9a3e0a6c59/plugins/woocommerce/client/legacy/js/frontend/password-strength-meter.js

What this file does is disable the save settings button until the password field meets all requirements. So I took advantage of this feature by pasting the original js code into my custom js file. Obviously I made some changes but only to the css classes to work with my custom form. (For those who ask, the js file contains html tags with css classes, these communicate with the form).

**So in the end I found myself with**:

1. form-edit-account.php (theme-child / woocommerce / myaccount)
2. form-edit-account.js (theme-child / woocommerce / myaccount / assets)
3. form-edit-account.css (theme-child / woocommerce / myaccount / assets)

All three files are in my child theme, I have written the path in parentheses for anyone trying to do the same, although this is subjective, but it is only an indication.

So what is in password-strength-meter.js I have pasted into form-edit-account.js file which contains my custom js. Below I leave the whole snippet for anyone interested, of course it is not playable here on stackoverflow, but it works on the live website.

**This is what the final result looks like**:

[image]

```js
/* Show Hide Password */    
function showPassword(targetID) {
    var pw = document.getElementById(targetID);
    if (pw.type === "password") {
      pw.type = "text";
    } else {
      pw.type = "password";
    }
  }

/*Add class Active to Modifica password*/
document.getElementById('editpw').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('actived');
}
  
/* Dropdown Password Field */
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_btn');
iconDrop = null;
lastOpened = null; //Add this for toggling dropdown
  
 dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dropCont = this.nextElementSibling;
    let icon = this.querySelector('.icon_item');
    icon.classList.toggle("down");
    dropCont.classList.toggle("show");
  
    //Add this for toggling dropdown
    if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== dropCont)
    lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
    lastOpened = dropCont;
  
    if (iconDrop && iconDrop !== icon)
    iconDrop.classList.remove("down");
    iconDrop = icon;
  }));

// Start Strength Meter Password

/* global wp, pwsL10n, wc_password_strength_meter_params */
( function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
/**
 * Password Strength Meter class.
 */
var wc_password_strength_meter = {

  /**
   * Initialize strength meter actions.
   */
  init: function() {
    $( document.body )
      .on(
        'keyup change',
        'form.register #reg_password, form.checkout #account_password, ' +
        'form.mts-edit-account #password_1, form.lost_reset_password #password_1',
        this.strengthMeter
      );
    $( 'form.checkout #createaccount' ).trigger( 'change' );
  },

  /**
   * Strength Meter.
   */
  strengthMeter: function() {
    var wrapper     = $( 'form.register, form.checkout, form.mts-edit-account, form.lost_reset_password' ),
      submit        = $( 'button[type="submit"]', wrapper ),
      field         = $( '#reg_password, #account_password, #password_1', wrapper ),
      strength      = 1,
      fieldValue    = field.val(),
      stop_checkout = ! wrapper.is( 'form.checkout' ); // By default is disabled on checkout.

    wc_password_strength_meter.includeMeter( wrapper, field );

    strength = wc_password_strength_meter.checkPasswordStrength( wrapper, field );

    // Allow password strength meter stop checkout.
    if ( wc_password_strength_meter_params.stop_checkout ) {
      stop_checkout = true;
    }

    if (
      fieldValue.length > 0 &&
      strength < wc_password_strength_meter_params.min_password_strength &&
      -1 !== strength &&
      stop_checkout
    ) {
      submit.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' ).addClass( 'disabled' );
    } else {
      submit.prop( 'disabled', false ).removeClass( 'disabled' );
    }
  },

  /**
   * Include meter HTML.
   *
   * @param {Object} wrapper
   * @param {Object} field
   */
  includeMeter: function( wrapper, field ) {
    var meter = wrapper.find( '.woocommerce-password-strength' );

    if ( '' === field.val() ) {
      meter.hide();
      $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc-password-strength-hide' );
    } else if ( 0 === meter.length ) {
      field.after( '<div class="woocommerce-password-strength" aria-live="polite"></div>' );
      $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc-password-strength-added' );
    } else {
      meter.show();
      $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc-password-strength-show' );
    }
  },

  /**
   * Check password strength.
   *
   * @param {Object} field
   *
   * @return {Int}
   */
  checkPasswordStrength: function( wrapper, field ) {
    var meter   = wrapper.find( '.woocommerce-password-strength' ),
      hint      = wrapper.find( '.woocommerce-password-hint' ),
      hint_html = '<small class="woocommerce-password-hint">' + wc_password_strength_meter_params.i18n_password_hint + '</small>',
      strength  = wp.passwordStrength.meter( field.val(), wp.passwordStrength.userInputDisallowedList() ),
      error     = '';

    // Reset.
    meter.removeClass( 'short bad good strong' );
    hint.remove();

    if ( meter.is( ':hidden' ) ) {
      return strength;
    }

    // Error to append
    if ( strength < wc_password_strength_meter_params.min_password_strength ) {
      error = ' - ' + wc_password_strength_meter_params.i18n_password_error;
    }

    switch ( strength ) {
      case 0 :
        meter.addClass( 'short' ).html( pwsL10n['short'] + error );
        meter.after( hint_html );
        break;
      case 1 :
        meter.addClass( 'bad' ).html( pwsL10n.bad + error );
        meter.after( hint_html );
        break;
      case 2 :
        meter.addClass( 'bad' ).html( pwsL10n.bad + error );
        meter.after( hint_html );
        break;
      case 3 :
        meter.addClass( 'good' ).html( pwsL10n.good + error );
        break;
      case 4 :
        meter.addClass( 'strong' ).html( pwsL10n.strong + error );
        break;
      case 5 :
        meter.addClass( 'short' ).html( pwsL10n.mismatch );
        break;
    }

    return strength;
  }
};

wc_password_strength_meter.init();
})( jQuery );
```

```css
/*Form Style*/
.mts-edit-account {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%) 0px 5px 15px -5px;
  border: 1px solid var(--e-global-color-2075d85);
}
.box-name-surname { 
  display: flex; gap: 20px; 
}
.form-row { 
  width: 100%; margin-bottom: 18px!important; 
}

.edit-account-button { height: 30px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; }
.edit-account-button.disabled { background-color: #8C9099; }
.edit-account-button.disabled:hover { background-color: #8C9099; }

fieldset { 
  border: 0!important; margin: 0!important; padding: 5px!important; 
}

/*Input fields*/
input.field-settings {
    width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px!important;
  border: 2px solid #efefef!important;
  padding: 12px!important;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 20px;
}

input.field-settings:focus {
  border: 2px solid #6FA4F2!important;
}

input.field-settings.disabled {
    background: var(--e-global-color-2606bfd);
    color: var(--e-global-color-43596cc);
}

label.t2 {
    font-size: 14px!important;
    line-height: 1.5em!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
    margin-bottom: 6px!important;
    display: block;
}

span.t4-light {
    margin: 0 6px;
  display: block;
}

/*Toggle Password*/
.togglePw { display: none; margin-bottom: 0;}

.togglePw + label:before { 
    content: "\f06e"; 
    font: var(--fa-font-solid); 
    margin-bottom: 6px; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
    display: block;
    color: #8C9099;
}

.togglePw:checked + label:before { 
    content: "\f070"; 
    font: var(--fa-font-solid);
    margin-bottom: 6px; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
    display: block;
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.input-group { display: flex; align-items: center; }

/*Dropdown Function Style*/
.drop_btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.drop_btn:hover {
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.drop_btn.actived {
    color: #1E70EB;
}

.icon_item {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f078';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.icon_item.down {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: '\f325';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 900px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/*Pasword Strength Meter*/
/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}


/*Woocommerce Password Strength Meter*/
.woocommerce-password-strength.short {
   background-color: #ffffff00;
   border-color: #ffffff00;
   text-align: right;
   color: #E11536;
   padding: 5px;
}
.woocommerce-password-strength.short:after {
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   font: var(--fa-font-solid);
   content: '\e368';
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.woocommerce-password-strength.bad {
   background-color: #ffffff00;
   border-color: #ffffff00;
   text-align: right;
   color: #EA580C;
   padding: 5px;
}
.woocommerce-password-strength.bad:after {
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   font: var(--fa-font-solid);
   content: '\e36f';
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.woocommerce-password-strength.good {
   background-color: #ffffff00;
   border-color: #ffffff00;
   text-align: right;
   color: #1E70EB;
   padding: 5px;
}
.woocommerce-password-strength.good:after {
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   font: var(--fa-font-solid);
   content: '\f11a';
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.woocommerce-password-strength.strong {
   background-color: #ffffff00;
   border-color: #ffffff00;
   text-align: right;
   color: #00B86E;
   padding: 5px;
}
.woocommerce-password-strength.strong:after {
   font-family: fontAwesome;
   font: var(--fa-font-solid);
   content: '\f4da';
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.woocommerce-password-hint {
   font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #8C9099;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://my-website.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.css?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" />
<script src="https://my-website.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.js?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" defer=""></script>

<form class="mts-edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>
   <div class="box-name-surname">
        <p class="form-row">
         <label class="t2" for="account_first_name">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="John"/>
       </p>
       <p class="form-row">
         <label class="t2" for="account_last_name">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="Doe" />
       </p>
   </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row">
     <label class="t2" for="account_user_login">Username</label>
     <input type="text" class="field-settings disabled" name="account_user_login" id="account_user_login" disabled value="JohnDoe" /> <span class="t4-light">Description here</span>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
     <label class="t2" for="account_display_name">Display Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="JohnDoe" /> <span class="t4-light">This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews</span>
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row email">
     <label class="t2" for="account_email">Email address<span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="email" class="field-settings" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="JohnDoe@example.com" />
    </p>

    <!-- Password Section -->
    <div id="editpw" class="drop_btn">Modifica Password<i class="icon_item fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
   <div class="drop_container">
       <fieldset>  
         <p>
               <label class="t2" for="password_current">Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off"/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_current" onclick="showPassword('password_current')"/>
                <label for="pw_current" class="fa"></label>
               </div>
         </p>

           <p>
               <label class="t2" for="password_1">New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off"/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_1" onclick="showPassword('password_1')"/>
                <label for="pw_1" class="fa"></label>
            </div>
                <div class="woocommerce-password-strength"></div>
         </p>

           <p>
              <label class="t2" for="password_2">Confirm new password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
                 <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_2" onclick="showPassword('password_2')"/>
                 <label for="pw_2" class="fa"></label>
            </div>
         </p>
      </fieldset>
   </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
     <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
     <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva modifiche', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```